# Python Django Profiling

Tags: python, django, graph, profiling, python-2.7

**Problem:**

I have a Django application. At the development stage I want to check

1. The **number of users** my app can support. **These users can be**:

   - users stored in the database
   - concurrent users
2. Find speed improvements, for example chunks of slow code

**Tools Used:**

I have installed django-debug-toolbar, which shows the **Time (CPU) and SQL queries**.

**What I want:**

I specifically want particular graphs or contitative data which can be presented to a large scale audience and on which improvements can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an app for that matter.

You can use apache `ab` to measure how many requests your app can handle on a givel URL.

```
ab -c 5 -n 1000 http://yoururlhere.com
```

See the [ab docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) for more.

Your "users stored in the database" are limited by your servers hard disk space available, so this should not be a problem.

To find slow code the django toolbar is a good start. If you finde a site that takes long time to load, you can investigate which methods causing this by manually adding:

```
import logging
def my_slow_code(self):
  start = time.time()
  [slow code]
  logging.debug('my_slow_code took %s s to load' % str(time.time()-start))
```